# Cannot call value of non-function type 'URL'

Tags: swift, url, xcode10, xcode11.3, createml

I am following The Complete iOS App Development Bootcamp by Angela, and I am in lesson [353](https://www.udemy.com/course/ios-13-app-development-bootcamp/learn/lecture/16828290#questions). My question is how to solve the error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'URL'".
My code so far is simply of three lines

```
import Cocoa
import CreateML

let data = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/user/Documents/CurrentProjects/Work/Mini/Twittermenti-iOS13-master/twitter-sanders-apple3.csv"))
```

The instructor is not facing the problem on Xcode 10 Beta while I am on Xcode 11.3.1 but I face the problem while following the exact same code.
Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Do you have any variable or class/struct named URL that you have created yourself? What happens if you replace URL with Foundation.URL?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I dont have any variable or class/struct named URL that I have created myself and when I add Foundation I receive error "Module 'Foundation' has no member named '<#T##URL#>'"Which I am not sure what even means

Comment: @JoakimDanielson based on usage of `MLDataTable` the OP is using MacOS, hence `import Cocoa` and not `Foundation` is correct.

Comment: @KirilS. Of course you can import only Foundation for macOS, I do it all the time

Comment: @Impostor_Syndrom_Incarnated could you perhaps include some more code related to the error, like the surrounding code lines?

Comment: Also, the following works fine for me `let url = Foundation.URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/...")` so in your case `let data = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: Foundation.URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/..."))` should work fine.

Comment: @KirilS. But you did bring up an interesting point, MLDataTable is MacOS only but OP is taking an iOS programming course so something is fishy here.

Comment: @Impostor_Syndrom_Incarnated Is this an iOS or a macOS project you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely somewhere you defined a variable like this:

[image]

hence you are overwriting a [URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url) class (an instance of which you are trying to create), with your local variable.

Change your local variable to lower-case (which is Swift standard anyways), and it will work:

```
import Cocoa
import CreateML

var url: URL

let data = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/user/Documents/CurrentProjects/Work/Mini/Twittermenti-iOS13-master/twitter-sanders-apple3.csv"))
```